# I'd like some clarification in this theorem proof.

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

Let $(P,Sc,1)$ a Peano's system, then $P=\{1\}\cup Sc\{P\}$

They use the third Peano's axiom, in which if $A\subseteq P, 1\in A$ and $Sc(a)\subseteq A\Rightarrow A=P$.
But their proof says in the begining: It's enough to prove that $Sc(A)\subseteq A$

How do they know that $A\subseteq P$?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand your question, but I think the answer may be that when discussing the Peano axioms, you cannot refer to things outside of $P $.

Comment: I just added a missing "P", the axiom asks that "$A\subseteq P$" as first requirement, but in the proof i was given, theres no proof that $A\subseteq P$, like it's obvious :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $P$ is closed under sucessors, i.e., $\operatorname{Sc}(P)\subseteq P$. Also, by definition $1\in P$, so $\{1\}\subseteq P$.

So if we define $A=\{1\}\cup\operatorname{Sc}(P)$, it is the union of two subsets of $P$, hence a subset of $P$ itself. The proof goes on to showing that $1\in A$ and $\operatorname{Sc}(A)\subseteq A$, from which the third Peano axiom (induction) implies that $P=A=\{1\}\cup\operatorname{Sc}(P)$.